# Change Network Type for Adaptor (Public vs Private)

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, network-adapter

I'm working on Windows 8.1 Professional. The machine is currently configured "Private" in a place that should be "Public". In its docs, Microsoft refers to this as "Public Mode" and "Private Mode" (see the KB below). The machine is *not* part of a HomeGroup.

[image]

I want to change the type to "Public", but I'm having trouble locating information on it (is it really intended to be this difficult?). I can find stuff on turning sharing on/off, changing HomeGroups settings, etc (some of the links below). But nothing that simply states how to change the adaptor's setting from "Private" to "Public".

***Note well***: Sharing on/off does not equate to public/private. I tried it, and I can say for certain that's not it on Windows 8.1.

How does one change the adaptor's setting from "Private" to "Public"? Screen captures would be very helpful because little of what I am finding is actually matching what I see.

---

Similar issues and searches:

- [Can't change network type in Windows 8](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/cant-change-network-type-in-windows-8/2d07a961-62e5-4d0b-926f-0e2f63116b02)
- [Windows 7 Network connections are stuck in Public mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2578723)
- [How do I set my wireless network to be private instead of public?](https://superuser.com/q/395606/173513) (Super User)
- [How to change from Public network to Private network](https://superuser.com/q/292678/173513) (Super User)
- [Google Search for Network Adaptor Public Mode](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+network+adaptor+%22public+mode%22)
- [Google Search for Network Adaptor Private Mode](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+network+adaptor+%22private+mode%22)

---

[How to change from Public network to Private network](https://superuser.com/q/292678/173513) (on Super User) says to delete the connection and start over. The problem is slightly different, and I'm hoping for something less destructive (it seems to be killing a fly with a cannon ball).

---

This is how maddening the problem is. I run through the Network Troubleshooter to try and get to a place to manually change things (as suggested in a number of hits on the web):

[image]

Ass soon as I click on "Explore Additional Options", it takes me to this useless screen:

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/395606/how-do-i-set-my-wireless-network-to-be-private-instead-of-public

Comment: @Maudam - I take that back. I *think* Huynh's answer solved the problem. But it did not appear solved until after I rebooted (I recall checking before the reboot, but did not see the switch from Private -> Public). So thank you. I cast the first duplicate close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who stumble upon this, I believe the answer was provided by Huynh in [How do I set my wireless network to be private instead of public?](https://superuser.com/a/507390/173513).

I can only say *"I believe"* because it took a reboot to get the expected result. But the reboot followed a few turns of a few different knobs, so I can't say for certain.

Its really unfortunate that Microsoft made recovering from a simple typo so difficult.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by PowerShell:

```powershell
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name Network -NetworkCategory Public
```

Comment: Docs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899565(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: Previous link is dead. Current documentation can be found at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netconnection/set-netconnectionprofile?view=win10-ps.

Answer (score 0):

2021 update* Powershell answer still works, but none of the others do. So here is a new, simple GUI alternative:

- Open Network and Internet Settings from the taskbar:
  [image: 1]
- Click properties on your **active** adapter or connection:
  [image: 2]
- Click Private to enable network sharing and discovery:
  [image: 3]

(*) This 6 years old question is the first result on Google when searching for "change network type" but all available graphical answers became outdated, so I'm posting a Windows 10 answer here.